# PhantomJS can't retrieve a website's entire html / can't find web elements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to use phantomjs for headless browser testing, and I noticed that simple commands like driver.get(By.id("")) were returning with an element not found exception. I did manage to find the source of the problem. I did a driver.getPageSource(), and noticed that phantomjs was not retrieving or "seeing" the complete page html.

The code below is what I'm trying to run. I am trying to find the searchbox on the Google home page. Viewing the HTML in the browser, you can see that the id for the searchbox is "lst-ib". However, upon doing the getPageSource(), "lst-ib" is missing from the result. This isn't a huge deal because I can still access the element by name. But on other web pages, entire chunks of HTML are missing, which results in whole elements being completely omitted from the getPageSource(). This makes Testing those elements impossible.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class AccessMessageDataRetentionSettings
{
    public WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        File f = new File("My path to the phantomjs executable");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", f.getAbsolutePath());
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        //caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--ssl-protocol=any", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--web-security=false" });
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var s=window.document.createElement('script'); s.src='path to my javascript file'; window.document.head.appendChild(s);");
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lst-ib")));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() 
    {
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 'lst-ib']"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));    
    }

    @After
    public void afterTest()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }   
}
```

Things I've tried: Declaring the webdriver as a PhantomJSDriver, setting different combinations of DesiredCapabilities (including setting the ssl-protocol to tlsv1), executing a javascript shim suggested from https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/945 via javascriptExecutor (which doesn't seem to be doing anything), and trying the various waits available in Selenium.

Is PhantomJS just not compatible with modern websites, or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Google delivers different pages depending on requesting browser. So the page will differ when opened in desktop browser or PhantomJS. Furthermore, PhantomJS has a lot of bugs, so this might come into play, but this is not really an answerable question. Many "modern" websites work quite well with PhantomJS. Some don't work at all. Website designers don't test their pages with PhantomJS-compatibility in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS is headless browser so many options that you can handle in firefox, IE and chrome will be impossible for example:

**Unsupported Features**

Support for plugins (such as Flash) was dropped a long time ago. The primary reasons:

- Pure headless (no X11) makes it impossible to have windowed plugin
  Issues and bugs are hard to debug, due to the proprietary nature of such plugins (binary blobs)
  The following features, due to the nature of PhantomJS, are irrelevant:
- WebGL would require an OpenGL-capable system. Since the goal of PhantomJS is to become 100% headless and self-contained, this is not acceptable. Using OpenGL emulation via Mesa can overcome the limitation, but then the performance would degrade.
- Video and Audio would require shipping a variety of different codecs.
- CSS 3-D needs a perspective-correct implementation of texture mapping. It can’t be implemented without a penalty in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. PhantomJS ended up being way too outdated and buggy to use. I ended up using docker containers running firefox/chrome images, then ran my tests on those with a RemoteWebDriver. Even though that means they are running on actual browsers within the containers, it was "headless" on my end, and that was good enough for my purposes.